# Query execution time reduction

Tags: sql, sql-server, time, execution

How to reduce the execution time of this simple SQL query in SQL Server?

```
select * 
from companybackup  
where tiRecordStatus = 1
and (iAccessCode < 3 or chUpdateBy = SUSER_SNAME())
```

It has nearly 38,681 rows and taking nearly 10 minutes 23 seconds. The table is having 50 columns and even I created indexes on all columns to reduce the time but it didn't succeed, even I checked with nolock option and all the available solutions but couldn't reduce the execution time.

What might be the issue?

Comment: What columns have indexes? What does EXPLAIN say?

Comment: actually in my existing code, instead of * ,they mentioned all the available columns,so i posted here as '*' and in a hurry i created individual indices for evry column instead of a single index,ignore what i had done and suggest me what needs to b done :):)

Answer (score 0):

If this is a critical query, you can create an index designed just for it:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_MyIndexNameHere ON CompanyBackup 
           (tiRecordStatus, iAccesscode, chUpdateBy)
```

This will still require a key lookup since you are returning all fields with `*`, but it's a lot better than a bunch of single-field indexes.

Comment: Then you didn't tell us everything about the situation.  Are there joins?  Other filters?  Can you post the table schema?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given much info, but splitting OR into a union of two queries can often help (optimisers have trouble with OR):

```
select * 
from companybackup  
where tiRecordStatus = 1
and iAccessCode < 3
union
select * 
from companybackup  
where tiRecordStatus = 1
and chUpdateBy = SUSER_SNAME())
```

If this doesn't help, try creating these indexes:

```
create index idx1 on companybackup(tiRecordStatus, iAccessCode);
create index idx2 on companybackup(chUpdateBy, tiRecordStatus);
```

Then force a recalculation if the distribution of index values:

```
update statistics companybackup;
```

Comment: hi bohemian...thanks for quick response,it still takes same amount of time, plz ask me if u need any further info...

Comment: even though...still it takes 10 minutes time :'(, plzz suggest @Bohemian

Comment: How many rows in your table? How many rows expected to match? Please show EXPLAIN output.

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering what does the SUSER_SNAME() function do, now it gets executed on every row. Can you try getting that function return value to parameter and then execute the query?

If the function is costly this will reduce execution time by a huge margin.

edit. Can anyone tell me why I can not post some SQL clauses and some I can? Cant post DECLARE syntax.

Comment: Hi @Janne Matikainen...even after replacing that function with parameter there was no change in execution time :(....plz ask me if you require any other info :)